# how to get gravity sensor information?

Tags: android

i'm trying to write an app for testing sensors by my Nexus S.

well , i wrote this to show the sensors lists through a listview.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //get all sensors
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sensorListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sensor_listview);
        sensorListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                showSensorInfo(sensors.get(position).getType());
            }
        });



        //set an empty adapter for ListView
        sensorNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);


        for (Sensor s : sensors) {
            sensorNames.add(s.getName());
            Log.i("sensor", s.getName());
        }
        sensorListView.setAdapter(sensorNames);
    }
```

i saw this ~
[image]

there is a sensor called 「Gravity Sensor」,

my question is , there are sensors CONSTANT such as :

Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER

Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE

Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT
..
.

and so on .But i couldn't find a CONSTANT called  「Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY」

where is the Gravity Sensor from =..=a?? ( i'm a really newbie~ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gravity is measured by the accelerometer but you can look up the gravity constant (approximately 9.8m/s^2.) The method to get an accurate constant is  SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY
You can look up the full use on 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#STANDARD_GRAVITY

Comment: The OP probably meant Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY which is a virtual sensor that uses (doesn't have to, but that's the whole point) not just accelerometer, but also gyro and compass to produce much more accurate and responsive results.

Answer (score 1):

`TYPE_GRAVITY` exists: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html
but its only available from Android 2.3 onwards. so check that in your app.